# Can someone explain how this code execution is happening?

Tags: system-verilog

```
module test;
 int j;
 initial begin
 for(j=0;j<3;j=j+1)
    fork
      $display("inside fork join",j);
    join_none
 $display(j);
end  
endmodule
```

I am really confused about the values I see in the output. Can someone please explain how it is working.

OUTPUT:

```
# KERNEL:           3
# KERNEL: inside fork join          3
# KERNEL: inside fork join          3
# KERNEL: inside fork join          3
```

Comment: It is inside a for loop.

Comment: Similar question on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45608673/why-does-the-output-always-print-j-5-in-fork-join-none)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `fork/join_none` does not start any of those threads until after the parent thread blocks or terminates. In your case, it's after the `initial` block process terminates. By that time, the value of `j` is 3 after exiting the `for` loop`.

To get your code to display 0,1, and 2 (in any order as three threads are forked off concurrently), you cannot use a single static variable for `j`. You need a create a copy of `j` for each iteration of the `for` loop using an `automatic` that gets initialized with the current value of `j` for each loop.

```
module test;
 int j;
 initial begin
 for(j=0;j<3;j=j+1)
    fork
      automatic int i = j
      $display("inside fork join",i);
    join_none
 $display(j);
end  
endmodule
```

Comment: Exactly, as per SV-LRM "spawned processes do not start executing until the parent thread executes a blocking statement". @AugmentiuM that's why in your case, the "for loop" unfolded completely, and then fork join_none threads are started.

Comment: Hi dave, in this case is ```automatic int i = j``` a statement that blocks the parent thread? I see that a blocking assignment is used so I'd like to know if the presence of a blocking assignment means "blocking" the parent thread.

Comment: This happens to be a _declaration initialization_ not a _blocking assignment_ or _blocking statement_.

BTW, a _blocking assignment_ has the potential to become a _blocking statement_. It is only a blocking statement if there are intra-assignment delays. e.g. `A = #1 B;`.